# Material-Table make clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using material-table to create a table from an array of products. https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

Here is my current code.

```
<MaterialTable
    title=""
    style={{boxShadow: "none"}}
    columns={[
        { title: 'Title', field: 'ProductTitle' },
        { title: 'Status', field: 'Status' },
        { title: 'Email', field: 'BuyerEmail' },
        { title: 'ID', field: 'id' },                   
    ]}
    data={this.state.ProductList}    
    options={{
        filtering: true,
        rowStyle: (data, index) => {
            if (index % 2) {
                return {backgroundColor: "#F8F9FC"}
            }
        }           
    }}                  
/>
```

The goal is to be able to click on a row in the table and for it to link to the individual product. The URL structure of the products go as follows: `mysite.com/product/id`. (The `id` is the one being displayed in `{ title: 'ID', field: 'id' }`)

I did notice they had a prop `onRowClick` and this example here https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/820 . But was generating too many errors.

The goal is:

- To make each row linked to their individual URL page and to add a CSS class to hover row.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
      <MaterialTable
        onRowClick={(event, rowData) => {
          // Get your id from rowData and use with link.
          window.open(`mysite.com/product/${rowData.id}`, "_blank")
          event.stopPropagation();
        }}
      ...
```

Check here - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-selection-different-data-from-table-txl39?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you for your response, so I added that code, and when I click the row it sends back an array with that individual information. But, I'm not sure how to make that row open a url link of the product instead.

Comment: you can use this to open with new tab with your informations window.open("mysite.com/product/id", "_blank") ?

Comment: Can you add that code to your response, this way I can make it the correct answer if it works.

Comment: yes, you can create like this and i guess you can get your id from rowData.

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea now instead of the last column displaying the ID, that it would just display a button that says "View"

Comment: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding  you can use this, look Action Overriding Example